# How do you repair active directory after a partially renamed domain controller?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller

I have a 2008 Server (only DC in the domain) which crashed during a rename.
As a result it left the system half renamed.
The computer name had been changed to DC1 but there were still many references to DC2 (the old computer name) such as in DNS and Active directory.

As a result the Netlogon service will not start and Active directory cannot be accessed.
After about 8 hours of hard work, I manged to make some progress by manualy editing DNS records and update Active Directory records using ADSIEdit.

When i run netdiag i get the following output...

```
Computer Name: DC1
DNS Host Name: dc1.school.local
System info : Windows Server (R) 2008 Standard (Build 6002)
Processor : x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 11, GenuineIntel
Hotfixes : none detected

Netcard queries test . . . . . . . : Passed
    [WARNING] The net card 'RAS Async Adapter' may not be working because it has not    received any packets.
GetStats failed for 'isatap.{A9F5A39A-FD61-44C4-BE9F-1E4BD5A3B546}'. [ERROR_GEN_FAILURE]

Per interface results:

Adapter : Local Area Connection

    Netcard queries test . . . : Passed

    Host Name. . . . . . . . . : dc1
    IP Address . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3
    Subnet Mask. . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway. . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
    Dns Servers. . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3
                                 127.0.0.1


    AutoConfiguration results. . . . . . : Passed

    Default gateway test . . . : Passed

    NetBT name test. . . . . . : Passed
    [WARNING] At least one of the <00> 'WorkStation Service', <03> 'Messenger Service', <20> 'WINS' names is missing.

    WINS service test. . . . . : Skipped
        There are no WINS servers configured for this interface.

Global results:

Domain membership test . . . . . . : Passed

NetBT transports test. . . . . . . : Passed
List of NetBt transports currently configured:
    NetBT_Tcpip_{A9F5A39A-FD61-44C4-BE9F-1E4BD5A3B546}
1 NetBt transport currently configured.

Autonet address test . . . . . . . : Passed

IP loopback ping test. . . . . . . : Passed

Default gateway test . . . . . . . : Passed

NetBT name test. . . . . . . . . . : Passed
[WARNING] You don't have a single interface with the <00> 'WorkStation Service', <03> 'Messenger Service', <20> 'WINS' names defined.

Winsock test . . . . . . . . . . . : Passed

DNS test . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Failed
   [FATAL] File \config\netlogon.dns contains invalid DNS entries.       [FATAL] File \config\netlogon.dns contains invalid DNS entries.    [FATAL] No DNS servers have the DNS records for this DC registered.

Redir and Browser test . . . . . . : Passed
List of NetBt transports currently bound to the Redir
    NetBT_Tcpip_{A9F5A39A-FD61-44C4-BE9F-1E4BD5A3B546}
The redir is bound to 1 NetBt transport.

List of NetBt transports currently bound to the browser
    NetBT_Tcpip_{A9F5A39A-FD61-44C4-BE9F-1E4BD5A3B546}
The browser is bound to 1 NetBt transport.

DC discovery test. . . . . . . . . : Failed
    [FATAL] Cannot find DC in domain 'SCHOOL'. [ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN]

DC list test . . . . . . . . . . . : Failed
    'SCHOOL': Cannot find DC to get DC list from [test skipped].

Trust relationship test. . . . . . : Skipped

Kerberos test. . . . . . . . . . . : Skipped
    'SCHOOL': Cannot find DC to get DC list from [test skipped].

LDAP test. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Failed
Cannot find DC to run LDAP tests on. The error occurred was: The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.


    [WARNING] Cannot find DC in domain 'SCHOOL'. [ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN]

Bindings test. . . . . . . . . . . : Passed

WAN configuration test . . . . . . : Skipped
No active remote access connections.

Modem diagnostics test . . . . . . : Passed

IP Security test . . . . . . . . . : Skipped

Note: run "netsh ipsec dynamic show /?" for more detailed information


The command completed successfully
```

and dcdiag returns....

```
Domain Controller Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
    Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\DC1
  Starting test: Connectivity
        *** Warning: could not confirm the identity of this server in
           the directory versus the names returned by DNS servers.
           If there are problems accessing this directory server then
           you may need to check that this server is correctly registered
           with DNS
     ......................... DC1 passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\DC1
  Starting test: Replications
     ......................... DC1 passed test Replications
  Starting test: NCSecDesc
     ......................... DC1 passed test NCSecDesc
  Starting test: NetLogons
     Unable to connect to the NETLOGON share! (\\DC1\netlogon)
     [DC1] An net use or LsaPolicy operation failed with error 67, Win32 Error 67.
     ......................... DC1 failed test NetLogons
  Starting test: Advertising
     Fatal Error:DsGetDcName (DC1) call failed, error 1355
     The Locator could not find the server.
     ......................... DC1 failed test Advertising
  Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders
     ......................... DC1 passed test KnowsOfRoleHolders
  Starting test: RidManager
     Failed with 8481: Win32 Error 8481
     Could not get Rid set Reference :failed with 8481: Win32 Error 8481
     ......................... DC1 failed test RidManager
  Starting test: MachineAccount
     ***Error: The server DC1 is missing its machine account.  Try running

     with the /repairmachineaccount option. 
     * The current DC is not in the domain controller's OU
     ......................... DC1 failed test MachineAccount
  Starting test: Services
        w32time Service is stopped on [DC1]
        NETLOGON Service is stopped on [DC1]
     ......................... DC1 failed test Services
  Starting test: ObjectsReplicated
     ......................... DC1 passed test ObjectsReplicated
  Starting test: frssysvol
     ......................... DC1 passed test frssysvol
  Starting test: frsevent
     There are warning or error events within the last 24 hours after the

     SYSVOL has been shared.  Failing SYSVOL replication problems may cause

     Group Policy problems. 
     ......................... DC1 failed test frsevent
  Starting test: kccevent
     An Warning Event occured.  EventID: 0x800004C8
        Time Generated: 07/01/2009   09:42:01
        Event String: An attempt by the local domain controller to

     An Warning Event occured.  EventID: 0x800004C8
        Time Generated: 07/01/2009   09:47:01
        Event String: An attempt by the local domain controller to

     ......................... DC1 failed test kccevent
  Starting test: systemlog
     An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0x000015E2
        Time Generated: 07/01/2009   09:42:21
        Event String: An internal error occurred while accessing the

     An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0xC25A002E
        Time Generated: 07/01/2009   09:42:23
        Event String: The time service encountered an error and was

     An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0xC0001B6F
        Time Generated: 07/01/2009   09:43:23
        (Event String could not be retrieved)
     An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0xC0001B6F
        Time Generated: 07/01/2009   09:43:23
        (Event String could not be retrieved)
     An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0xC0001B72
        Time Generated: 07/01/2009   09:43:23
        (Event String could not be retrieved)
     An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0x00000469
        Time Generated: 07/01/2009   09:45:00
        Event String: The processing of Group Policy failed because of

     An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0x00000456
        Time Generated: 07/01/2009   09:45:43
        Event String: The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows

     An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0xC000042B
        Time Generated: 07/01/2009   09:49:19
        Event String: The terminal server cannot register 'TERMSRV'

     ......................... DC1 failed test systemlog
  Starting test: VerifyReferences
     ......................... DC1 passed test VerifyReferences

Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
  Starting test: CrossRefValidation
     ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation
  Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
     ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom

Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
  Starting test: CrossRefValidation
     ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation
  Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
     ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom

Running partition tests on : Schema
  Starting test: CrossRefValidation
     ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation
  Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
     ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom

Running partition tests on : Configuration
  Starting test: CrossRefValidation
     ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation
  Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
     ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom

Running partition tests on : School
  Starting test: CrossRefValidation
     ......................... School passed test CrossRefValidation
  Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
     ......................... School passed test CheckSDRefDom

Running enterprise tests on : School.local
  Starting test: Intersite
     ......................... School.local passed test Intersite
  Starting test: FsmoCheck
     Warning: DcGetDcName(GC_SERVER_REQUIRED) call failed, error 1355
     A Global Catalog Server could not be located - All GC's are down.
     Warning: DcGetDcName(PDC_REQUIRED) call failed, error 1355
     A Primary Domain Controller could not be located.
     The server holding the PDC role is down.
     Warning: DcGetDcName(TIME_SERVER) call failed, error 1355
     A Time Server could not be located.
     The server holding the PDC role is down.
     Warning: DcGetDcName(GOOD_TIME_SERVER_PREFERRED) call failed, error 1355
     A Good Time Server could not be located.
     Warning: DcGetDcName(KDC_REQUIRED) call failed, error 1355
     A KDC could not be located - All the KDCs are down.
     ......................... School.local failed test FsmoCheck
```

from these I am certain the problem still lies with DNS, but not sure where.
Can anyone offer some advice?

Comment: When starting the netlogon service i get the following...

    The Netlogon Service could not be started.
    A system error has occured.
    System error 100 has occured.
    Cannot create another semaphore.

Comment: I take it that restoring from a backup made prior to the failed change is out of the question?

Comment: restore the demoted dc, then start over again!

Answer (score 2):

Can you restore back to before you renamed and start the process over again clean?

Comment: No unfortunatley this is a brand new server, and the old server has already been demoted (as the new server was up and running fine until the rename)

Comment: I'm confused. If it's a new server, can you not just reload it? If it's an old server, shouldn't you have a restore point? Since you've spent 8 hours on it already.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's a mess.

Ok, first I'd check FSMO roles by doing 'netdom query FSMO' and see if the old server name is the holder of any FSMO roles, if this is the case follow the instructions in the next link to seize the FSMO roles and get them under the right server name. Chances are not everything got transferred to the new name and you'll need to clean the metadata, this is done with the NTDSUTIL.

Cleaning the metadata -> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736378%28WS.10%29.aspx

Now, I'd run dcdiag /repairmachineaccount and see if that yeilds results, if it does it should fix the machine account and place it in the domain controllers OU.

Then run DCDIAG and NETDIAG again and start working on the individual errors. Google the error and see if you can fix their individual causes.

I'd look at this from the viewpoint of a failed DC that held the majority of the FSMO roles, the errors you are getting look more like the old server name holds the RID, Infrastructure and SCHEMA master even though its not showing up that way in the knowofroleholders test in dcdiag.